# How to count individual product price in order?

Tags: powerbi, dax

See this screenshot:

[image: orders]]

I have a bunch of orders with products in a list. Two products, marked red, are displayed in separate rows but products are the same.
The quantity did not not sum of those two products in database, but the total price is summed.

Problem is that `total price` shows the total sum of same two products. And if there are more than one same product in order displayed in separate row, those rows total price sums together.

Can anyone help me with filters? If in an order there is more than one of the same product displayed in separate row, I want that the total price won't be calculated between them.

I need another column, were price is calculated in this way:
if there is more than one product with same `product code` in same order (`order id`) then the `total price` should be devided by quantity of sum of same products

101023 | 2017-03-06 | 7610917627158 | 1 | 14.86 | 7.43 (new column)

101023 | 2017-03-06 | 7610917627158 | 1 | 14.86 | 7.43 (new column)

Comment: There's unfortunately still some language issues left I couldn't figure out while editing your question. It would help if you create an [mcve] with dummy data and English sample column names, and be explicit about the expected output.

Comment: Thank you Jeroen. I updated my question, maybe this way will be more easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

To get your desired result, you need to perform a calculation on a filtered row set. Luckily, PowerBI has a built in CALCULATE function that does just that.

Simply add a new column with the below DAX code and you will have a new column showing the subtotal for each row.

```
Subtotal = CALCULATE(Max(Orders[total price]) / SUM(Orders[quantity]), Orders[order id], Orders[Date], Orders[product code])
```

One note that is not really covered in the documentation - if you give the CALCULATE function a comma separated list of fields (as in this example), it compares those fields to the value of the current row.

[image: End results]

For more information on the CALCULATE function, check out the PowerBI documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634825.aspx).